# all tables form sql database not being mapped to entity framwork .edmx

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

i have come across a special situation , i am generating an entity framework to map all my tables for an .net  project , even all tables are being shown i checked them all of them before mapping ,Out of 6 tables 2 were mapped and 4 were not,What could be the reason if there is some kind of security or something else.

Tried with update model from database, selecting table again and adding them still ,it dint worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478912/ef-database-first-refusing-to-map-a-table   , kind of similar but not exactly does not help.

Comment: Please show the data model.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the tables in the list and can check them it is probably not a Security problem.

It could be:

- The tables are many-to-many link tables, which are shown in the diagram as a relationship not a table.
- The tables do not have a primary key / single Field unique index defined